# Docker containers inaccessible in browser after reboot - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian, container

Raspberry Pi 4
Raspberry Pi OS Lite
Docker 23.0.0

Docker containers are not accessible in the browser after reboot, I thought it may have been because the containers do not start, but it appears that they do. But I am not sure why they are inaccessible. As an attempted remedy, I ran the following commands:

```
docker run -d --restart always [Container]
```

or just:

```
docker start [Container]
```

The only solution I can seem to find is to reinstall the container, but that is useless because I lose data and have to set up the application again, after every reboot.

Here's what I've done:

I first checked the running containers:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   2 minutes ago   Up About a minute   8080/tcp                                   elegant_bhabha
```

Focussing on the searxng you can see it is running:

cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   2 minutes ago   Up About a minute   8080/tcp

Then I try to restart Searxng just to see if it will make it work in the browser:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker restart elegant_bhabha
elegant_bhabha
```

I proceed to check to see if Searxng has started and is accessible at 192.168.50.168:8080 in the browser, it is not.

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   3 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   8080/tcp                                   elegant_bhabha
```

Then I re-do the installation process to get it to work:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ cd my-instance
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ export PORT=8080
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker pull searxng/searxng
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from searxng/searxng
Digest: sha256:3d656c623ce5293633e4e0d7fcf4bc47e17dc4dc13d4300173b57b0d73879270
Status: Image is up to date for searxng/searxng:latest
docker.io/searxng/searxng:latest
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker run --rm \
             -d -p ${PORT}:8080 \
             -v "${PWD}/searxng:/etc/searxng" \
             -e "BASE_URL=http://localhost:$PORT/" \
             -e "INSTANCE_NAME=my-instance" \
             searxng/searxng
8b914f2122817a3f301fa0b550ccc600426728fe30098ae845d950547f1fa9b0
```

As you can see below, there is a change after reinstalling the container, after reinstallation the container is now accessible in the browser at 192.168.50.168:8080, but of course I have to again set up the application. I have to do this for every docker container I install after every reboot.

```
pi@raspberrypi4:~/my-instance $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
8b914f212281   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   15 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   gifted_gagarin
cea07c9a5d01   searxng/searxng          "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   7 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes    8080/tcp                                  elegant_bhabha
```

Every time I install any container, it works fine and is accessible in the browser. And then after reboot they don't work, and running restart commands doesn't work. I have no idea how to resolve this, any ideas?

Comment: Did you post this exact question yesterday? I made the comment that the PORTS looks odd in the "non working" container. I gather it's not just the `searxng/searxng` container that is failing like this? Other containers fail too? is there anything "interesting" in the logs when you boot regarding docker?

Comment: @JaromandaX I posted this in Raspberry Pi SE forum yesterday. It's ALL containers failing like this. I see a lot of "dockerd" and "containerd" entries in the syslog file, but I'm unsure what to make of them. Example: `dockerd[620]: time="2023-02-05T01:14:44.210272483+11:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"`

Comment: well, you can see them but don't understand them, we can't see them, and may be able to understand them

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to post the syslog file to pastebin but pastebin said it was too big to post. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @JaromandaX [syslog](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkE_tGoraJ7MiIoT3k4WWnsQDr_c9w?e=lhkoGe)

Comment: consider the "level=error" entries - the error is `"failed to load container mount"` - search for that, see if any of those results help